# How to update several DataFrames values with another DataFrame values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Please would you like to know how I can update two `DataFrames` `df1` y `df2` from another `DataFrame` `df3`. All this is done within a `for` loop that iterates over all the elements of the `DataFrame` `df3`

```py
for i in range(len(df3)):
   df1.p_mw = ...
   df2.p_mw = ...
```

The initial `DataFrames` `df1` and `df2` are as follows:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['GH_1', 10, 'Hidro'],
                    ['GH_2', 20, 'Hidro'],
                    ['GH_3', 30, 'Hidro']],
                    columns= ['name','p_mw','type'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['GT_1', 40, 'Termo'],
                    ['GT_2', 50, 'Termo'],
                    ['GF_1', 10, 'Fict']],
                    columns= ['name','p_mw','type'])
```

The `DataFrame` from which I want to update the data is:

```py
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[150,57,110,20,10],
                    [120,66,110,20,0],
                    [90,40,105,20,0],
                    [60,40,90,20,0]],
                    columns= ['GH_1', 'GH_2', 'GH_3', 'GT_1', 'GT_2'])
```

As you can see the `DataFrame` `df3` contains data from the corresponding column `p_mw` for both `DataFrames` `df1` and `df2`. Furthermore, the DataFrame df2 has an element named GF_1 for which there is no update and should remain the same.

After updating for the last iteration, the desired output is the following:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['GH_1', 60, 'Hidro'],
                    ['GH_2', 40, 'Hidro'],
                    ['GH_3', 90, 'Hidro']],
                    columns= ['name','p_mw','type'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['GT_1', 20, 'Termo'],
                    ['GT_2', 0, 'Termo'],
                    ['GF_1', 10, 'Fict']],
                    columns= ['name','p_mw','type'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **mapping** series by selecting the last row from `df3`, then `map` it on the column `name` and fill the nan values using the values from `p_mw` column

```
s = df3.iloc[-1]

df1['p_mw'] = df1['name'].map(s).fillna(df1['p_mw'])
df2['p_mw'] = df2['name'].map(s).fillna(df2['p_mw'])
```

If there are multiple dataframes that needed to be updated then we can use a for loop to avoid repetition of our code:

```
for df in (df1, df2):
    df['p_mw'] = df['name'].map(s).fillna(df['p_mw'])
```

---

```
>>> df1

   name  p_mw   type
0  GH_1    60  Hidro
1  GH_2    40  Hidro
2  GH_3    90  Hidro

>>> df2
   name  p_mw   type
0  GT_1  20.0  Termo
1  GT_2   0.0  Termo
2  GF_1  10.0   Fict
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do as you ask. No need for a for loop.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['GH_1', 10, 'Hidro'],
                    ['GH_2', 20, 'Hidro'],
                    ['GH_3', 30, 'Hidro']],
                    columns= ['name','p_mw','type'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['GT_1', 40, 'Termo'],
                    ['GT_2', 50, 'Termo'],
                    ['GF_1', 10, 'Fict']],
                    columns= ['name','p_mw','type'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame([[150,57,110,20,10],
                    [120,66,110,20,0],
                    [90,40,105,20,0],
                    [60,40,90,20,0]],
                    columns= ['GH_1', 'GH_2', 'GH_3', 'GT_1', 'GT_2'])

updates = df3.iloc[-1].values
df1["p_mw"] = updates[:3]
df2["p_mw"] = np.append(updates[3:], df2["p_mw"].iloc[-1])
```